# How to retrieve a Youtube page without starting to stream the video?

Tags: python, youtube

I'm actually not sure if it tries to stream the video at all, it just takes a few seconds longer than normal to parse a YouTube page.

I'm looking to parse a random Youtube video page to see if it has been removed or not, and I'm looking to make sure everything but the video itself gets loaded. I've got the following code that works, only that it takes a while for it to finish (I'm assuming the video starts to load which slows it down, haven't tested to confirm though)

```
import requests, bs4

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XYZ'
parameters = {'magic_var' : 'no_load'}
r = requests.get(url, params=parameters)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.content)
```

My question is whether or not there's some sort of parameter that I can set to make sure the video doesn't start loading immediately on a page request.

Comment: What are you going to do with the content? If you need certain information that can be retrieved from Youtub API, use the API.

Comment: Do you have flash inside Python to load the video???

Comment: @User007 purely parse whether or not it's been removed, by looking for a `h1` with a `unavailable-message` id. I will look into the YTAPI.

Comment: @JBernardo No, the example code is pretty much all I'll be doing with it. `soup.Find` is as far as I go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *browser* will stream the video on a separate request, after it loaded the page (and the flash player referenced by the page). The video is not part of the page data itself. Neither are the styles, scripts, and images; they are all just references encoded in the HTML page for the browser to interpret.

Just requesting the page in and of itself will not start the video being streamed, no.

In other words, all `requests.get()` will load is the basic HTML markup that your browser also loads. Unless you then interpret that HTML markup and start loading the resources referenced in the page, you will not automatically start loading anything else.

Comment: Okay, so it's just that the page is complex enough that `bs4` takes a a second or two to parse it. Thanks.

Comment: @TankorSmash: exactly. Perhaps use a different underlying parser (beautifulsoup can use several, perhaps `lxml` is going to be faster). Or perhaps the HTTP request is slow?

Comment: That was what I tried at first, but got a parsing error, though I didn't pay enough attention to the actual message to try and solve it.

Comment: With the `'lxml'` setting or the `'xml'` one? It could be the input HTML is malformed and that `lxml` wants to parse it in a stricter manner.

Comment: Should have been more specific, I just did something like `lxml.etree.parse(r.content)`, I haven't played around with anything else in `lxml`.

Comment: @TankorSmash: Ah, you should have used the [`lxml.html` module](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html) then. :-)

Comment: Oh well there you go! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

How about use network analyzers and see where the video coming from?
So far I understand that all the videos are coming from one host name:
example:

```
s.ytimg.com/yt/swfbin/watch_as3.swf?video_id=YOUR_VIDEO_ID&autoplay=1
```

and `autoplay` will eather be 1 - to start playin or 0.

If `video_id` is no longer exists, you will see something like `Invalid parameters` on the screen.